# Git : could not resolve bitbucket.org after Mojave update

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket

Yesterday i updated my MacBook Pro to Mojave because i needed to update Xcode.
The update was painfull but it finally succeed.

Now when i try to push my project (which worked well before the update), i got this error :

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: -65563
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I tried to invastiguate and tried some tips on the web :

- ping bitbucket.org : unknow host
- i changed my DNS to 8.8.8.8 : no change
- i can browse web pages included bitbucket.org
- i flushed DNS caches and no change
- i can't connect to my VPN server with the hostname but i can with the IP
- i added bitbucket IP in my Hosts file but nothing change execpt that pinging bitbucket.org timeout now.

All seems indicate a DNS issue but i have 2 Windows computer, and with them i can push with GIT. But when i try to ping bitbucket.org, i got unknow host too.
I can also connect to my VPN with the hostname on Windows.

I'm on it for 2 days and that start to make me crazy !
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe you have to force the use of IPv4 after your update? Or change from DNS to the IP address. Maybe that would help as workaround.

Comment: I just tried it and yes it work as workaround thank you ! Now i have to make it work normaly ...

Comment: Assuming you're still having DNS issues: try running `dig +short bitbucket.org` and `dig +short @8.8.8.8 bitbucket.org` — are both returning the same IP addresses?

Comment: Yes the two commands return the same result. Two month later i still have this issue ... If you have an idea, i'm very interested !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution :

- Reboot the computer
- Press Command + R on reboot
- Open a terminal and run :

  `csrutil disable`
- Reboot the computer
- Once rebooted, open a terminal and run :

  `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`
- And run :

  `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`

Done.

If i run `csrutil enable` it won't work again. I know it's not recommanded to let it disable but it's the only solution i found.